# Why the dual norm of a normed vector space is defined on the supremum on $||x||\leq 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

From a book I'm reading the definition of the dual norm of a n.v.s. $(X,||\cdot||)$ is defined as

$||f||_{X^*}:=\sup_{||x||\leq 1}|f(x)|, x\in X$ where $f\in X^*$

So why is it not defined like $||f||_{X^*}:=\sup_{||x||= 1}|f(x)|, x\in X$? Is there any instance that those two definitions are not equivalent?

Comment: The expressions are equivalent, and you should prove it :)  It's an exercise in many textbooks.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there's some significance in the choice of using $\leq$ instead of $=$ but I couldn't think of any.

Comment: Not really; but some arguments work better over the unit sphere and some over the unit ball, so it's convenient to be able to pick $=$ and $\leq$ for the sphere and ball without having to worry about whether the value of the norm changes slightly

Comment: There is exactly one case where you cannot use the second definition:  $X=\{0\}$!

Comment: Ah! I see. So that's why. Thank you.

Comment: There is one other case when $=$ gives you the wrong definition while $≤$ gives you the correct definition: If the base field is not $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ but another normed field like $\Bbb Q_p$ it can be that not every vector is proportional to something on the unit ball. But this is a vastly different context!